# ¿Estilos de CSS y Bootstrap 4?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

¿Como puedo eliminar ese borde que redondea a mi input y cambiar el color del background de B4? Estoy usando Angular y uso componentes por lo que no tengo nada como un body para poder asignar el color de fondo a dicha etiqueta.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**CSS**

```
.content {
  margin-top: 2em;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 18px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.41);
  border-radius: 30px 30px 30px 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

h3 {
  padding: 10px 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(75, 168, 255);
}

img {
  border-radius: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  margin-top: 2em;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}

input {
    text-align: center;
    width: 60%;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: rgb(235, 235, 235);
    height: 3em;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    border: 1px solid #FFF;
}

button {
    margin-top: 1em;
    text-align: center;
    width: 40%;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: rgb(75, 168, 255);
    height: 3em;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    border: 1px solid #FFF;
    color: white;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.email {
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.min-footer {
    margin-top: 2em;
    background-color: rgb(235, 235, 235);
    padding: 30px 0;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 30px 30px;
    color: rgb(75, 168, 255);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="content">
      <h3>Sing In</h3>
      <figure>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/people" alt="" />
      </figure>
      <div class="inp">
        <input type="text" class="email" placeholder="login" />
        <br>
        <input type="password" class="pass" placeholder="password" />
        <br>
        <button>Log in</button>
      </div>
      <div class="min-footer">
        <span>Forgot Password?</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Por favor añade tu código como texto y no como imagen, pues así es difícil reproducir un ejemplo

Comment: @Aprendiz Gracias por mencionarlo, lo habia olvidado :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A tu `input` se le esta aplicando un efecto llamado `outline` que son efectos al border las cajas de texto, entre los cuales tienes:

- `outline-style`
- `outline-width`
- `outline-color`

Entonces lo que debemos hacer es establecer a ninguno dicha propiedad, lo cual lo podemos hacer así:

```
.email{
    outline: none;
}
```

Para el caso del `background-color` del lienzo de tu página web, debes resetear dichos valores; considerando que el primer archivo invocado son los estilos CSS de Bootstrap 4, entonces deberías hacer lo siguiente:

Por lo que veo `.content` es la clase asignada al `div` principal que envuelve al resto de los elementos de tu componente entonces reescribe el estilo de color de fondo para ese nodo:

```
.content{
   background-color: otro-color;
}
```

Entonces el primer estilo aplicado ahí es el de Bootstrap pero como va en cascada después se modifica por que el colocamos de forma personzalizada